# Show that mutually orthogonal subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$ must have a collective dimension $\le n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V_1,...,V_k$ are mutually orthogonal subspaces of
>   $\mathbb{R^n}$ for $k\ge 2$. Show that $\dim(V_1)+...+\dim(V_k)\le n$.

I was trying to take the direction of using induction, because I've already proven the case when $k=2$. So I use the inductive hypothesis that $\dim(V_1)+...\dim(V_{k-1})\le n$ and try to use induction to show that $\dim(V_1)+...\dim(V_k)\le n$.

So we know that $V_1 \cap ... \cap V_k = \{\vec{0}\}$, and since $V_1,...,V_k$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$, we know that $span(V_1,...,V_k)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ so $\dim(V_1)+...+\dim(V_k)\le n$.

I have a few problems. First, I didn't really use the inductive hypothesis to solve the problem, it just seemed like simple reasoning. Secondly, I'm not sure if the proof is quite rigorous enough. Intuitively, I understand why the result must hold, I'm just not sure how to formally state it, especially when I'm trying to use induction and the stated inductive hypothesis.

Comment: It's not a true implication in general that $V_1\cap\cdots\cap V_k = \{0\}$ in $\Bbb R^n$ implies $\dim V_1 + \cdots + \dim V_k \le n$. For example, in $\Bbb R^3$ take $V_1,V_2,V_3$ to be the three coordinate planes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how one would actually prove this by induction, but here's a different way you could go about things:

Suppose that each $V_i$ from $i = 1,\dots,k$ has an orthogonal basis $B_i = \{v_{i,1},v_{i,2},\dots,v_{i,\dim(V_i)}\}$.  Verify that all vectors in the set $B = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_k$ are mutually orthogonal, so that $B$ is a collection of linearly independent vectors.

Note that the number of elements in $B$ is $\dim(V_1) + \cdots + \dim(V_k)$.